# MySQLi present still not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I ran `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));` and it returned boolean true.

I am running the following code

```
<?php
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","dbname") or      die("Unable to Connect");

    $showtablequery="SHOW TABLES FROM dbname";
    $query_result=mysqli_query($showtablequery);
    while($showtablerow = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
    echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
    } 
?>
```

It did not do anything. It did not print anything on the result webpage.

When I use mysql functions instead then it works fine.

What do I need to do to use mysqli function?

Comment: Add *actual* error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs. You have not passed the connection to the `mysqli_query()` function.

Comment: Pass in the connection or use the object oriented approach

Comment: [`$query_result=mysqli_query($showtablequery);` - *coughconnectcough*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: mysqli does _not_ know about a 'default connection' when using `procedural mode`. i.e. you always need to pass `$connect` explicitly when using  _`mysqli_query`_ and any others.  i.e. see what @Fred said :)

Comment: *"When I use mysql functions instead then it works fine."* - that's because `mysql_` doesn't always need a connection parameter be passed. `mysql_` and `mysqli_` are *two different animals altogether* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Oop

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","dbname") or      die("Unable to Connect");

    $showtablequery="SHOW TABLES FROM dbname";
    $query_result=$mysqli->query($showtablequery);
    while($showtablerow = $mysqli->fetch_array($query_result))
    {
    echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
    } 
?>
```

Even if you connected successfully, it cannot query the database without connection informatiokn.

### Procedural

```
<?php
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","dbname") or      die("Unable to Connect");

    $showtablequery="SHOW TABLES FROM dbname";
    $query_result=mysqli_query($connect, $showtablequery);
    while($showtablerow = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
    echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: huh? what difference could that make? the answer is simple; not connecting.

Comment: ah... an edit I see. comment ^ as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30899252/1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$query_result=mysqli_query($showtablequery);
```

use

```
$query_result=$connect->query($showtablequery);
```

and instead of

```
$showtablerow = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result);
```

use

```
$showtablerow = $query_result->fetch_array();
```

Comment: same here as I said below. and above

Comment: Is there any advantage of the procedural pattern over the OOP pattern?

Comment: Not really, but consistency is key